# JetBrains Rider | MassTransit Anonymous Type | MCA0003 | "Add Missing Properties" command does not autocomplete the properties

Tags: roslyn, jetbrains-ide, masstransit, rider

## Background

Operating Systems and IDEs Tested:
JetBrains Rider 2020.2.4 on Linux Elementary 5.1 Hera | Fail
JetBrains Rider 2020.2.4 on Windows 10 Home | Fail
Visual Studio Professional 2019 on Windows 10 Home | Success

Dotnet Version: .Net  Core 3.1

I'm following the tutorial Chris Patterson published on YouTube [MassTransit Starting with Mediator](https://youtu.be/dxHNAn69x6w?t=1050).  The link is timestamped to where my issue occurs.

NuGet Packages Installed:

- MassTransit.AspNetCore on the API Project,
- MassTransit.Analyzers 7.0.4 on the API and Components projects, and
- MassTransit 7.0.4 on the Components project.

## Issue

In the Request Client's GetResponse function, I created the anonymous type to represent the message contract.
I.e.:

```
var response = await _submitOrderRequestClient.GetResponse<OrderSubmissionAccepted>(new {});
```

The analyzer recognizes the properties are missing and provides the option "Add Missing Properties."  I clicked the button to add the properties; however, nothing happens.

## Question

How can I troubleshoot this issue further or resolve the issue?  This seems like a fantastic feature, and I'd really like to take advantage of it.

## Note

The issue is limited to JetBrains Rider 2020.2.3 and 2020.2.4 regardless of the operating system.  JetBrains has a ticket open as of 2020-10-07 [RIDER-52072](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-52072)

Comment: Have you contacted JetBrains?  I've found their customer support to be extremely responsive in the past.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because even though this is a well formatted issue report, it should just go to the official issue tracker, since probably no one here can help to fix the problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Comment: Broke for me as well on the latest Rider release, and 7.0.4. Worked on earlier versions.

Comment: Any luck on Windows with Visual Studio for comparison?

Comment: JetBrains has acknowledged the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-52072  Please upvote the issue in their system and please vote to close this question, per @ruohola.  Thanks to all for your quick responses.

Comment: @Trevor.Screws Please copy paste the whole issue report from this question to the youtrack issue, since if this question gets deleted we don't want only people with 10k StackOverflow reputation from being able to see the bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue as well, after updating today it works again.

Update: Build #RD-203.6110.173, built on November 24, 2020

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains marked as "Fixed" on 11/11/2020.